# IE Conditional Comment Issue

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, conditional-comments

On a new application we've made a decision to no longer support IE6, so we have a conditional comment to load a script that says as much.

Code is:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <h2 style="color:red;">Old Version of Internet Explorer Detected</h2>
            <p style="color:red;">It appears that you're using an old version of Microsoft
            Internet Explorer.  This site is optimized for Internet Explorer 
            7 and above as well as Mozilla Firefox.  Please download a 
            newer version of <a href="https://www.microsoft.com/windows/Internet-explorer/default.aspx">
            Internet Explorer</a> or <a href="https://www.mozilla.com/firefox/">Firefox</a>
            before continuing.
            </p>
<![endif]-->
```

However, for one company, the comment fires, despite their use of IE7 and IE8.

Here's the access log with info removed for privacy.

10.xxx.xx.xx - - [15/Aug/2011:17:18:54 -0500] "GET /broker/js/ie6.js HTTP/1.1" 200 147 "https://xx.xxxxx.com/broker/registration" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; **MSIE 7.0;** Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)" "en-us"

Any ideas??

Andy

Comment: My suggestion would be not to have the message in the first place. IE6 is so far in the past now. It is used by less then 10% of world! Even Microsoft are trying to kill it off: http://www.ie6countdown.com/

Comment: I agree, however, about 8% of our users still use IE6 and this particular app does not work properly if using anything less than IE7.  We chose not to add all the IE6 css and js hacks.

Answer (score 0):

IE 7 / 8 could be using IE6 ["compatibility mode"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: Does IE7 even have compatibility mode?

Comment: I thought it was IE 7 onwards, but I could be wrong. I don't have an IE 7 install to test with I'm afraid.